# Nginx site not responding on port 80

Tags: nginx

I have a new Ubuntu 16.04 LTS server where I have installed Nginx. This is my first Nginx server, I have only used Apache before.

I followed [the installation guide on this page](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04), and all steps executed without any errors. When I connect to the server via SSH, and check to see if the Nginx service is running, I get this response:

```
$ sudo service nginx status

● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: en
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2016-11-10 06:54:07 UTC; 1h 15min ago
  Process: 30097 ExecReload=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; -s 
 Main PID: 22172 (nginx)
    Tasks: 2
   Memory: 3.6M
      CPU: 25ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
           ├─22172 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_pr
           └─30100 nginx: worker process
```

It looks to me like my Nginx server is running and ready to serve web pages. My expectation at this point is that I should be able to open a browser, go to my IP, and then see the default Nginx HTML page.

**The problem:** When I open a browser and go to my IP address, I never see the default page. On Firefox, the loading indicator spins without ever stopping. In Chrome, it eventually ends with this message:

```
The ###.###.###.### page isn’t working
###.###.###.### didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

I checked the logs in `/var/log/nginx`, but `access.log` was empty, and `error.log` only contained this one line:

```
2016/11/10 08:03:41 [notice] 30097#30097: signal process started
```

The last thing I could think of was maybe the firewall was blocking it, but I believe I've opened the right ports using `ufw`:

```
$ sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
Nginx HTTP                 ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere                  
21/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Nginx Full                 ALLOW       Anywhere
```

For reference, my Nginx configuration file is [here on Pastebin](https://paste.ubuntu.com/23455071/).

**The question:** How do I get my Nginx server to respond by showing the default page when I access my server from a browser?

Comment: curl from your server rather than trying from your browser, this helps narrow down the problem. Post your nginx config.

Comment: @Tim, thank you for the response. I don't know what you mean by "curl from your server". I updated my question to include a link to the config file on Pastebin.

Comment: Run `curl http://server_IP_address` from your server. With -I if you just want the HTTP-header.

Comment: That config file you linked to does not contain site specific configurations, they are located in sites-enabled/ directory. This directory should contain configurations for any websites you wish to run - including configurations for open TCP ports. From your config file: include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

Comment: You aren't saying anything about what kind of server this is or where it is hosted. If it is hosted at a cloud provider or similar you might have to open up in a security group, set up port forwarding or similar. If you tell us where it is hosted it is far easier to give exact guidance.

Comment: @DavidB. Thank you for telling me the exact command. I tried it, but unfortunately, after a long delay, it only came back with this: `curl: (7) Failed to connect to ###.###.###.### port 80: Connection timed out`. I'm not sure this sheds any more light on the situation.

Comment: Right, OK, so as mentioned in the first answer, we don't know where your server is hosted. Google Cloud and AWS have their own Security/Firewall rules that you need to set, so would be good to have more info on that front.

Comment: Failed to connect suggests Nginx isn't running. You need to learn more about Nginx - read a tutorial, how the config file works, etc. You can't assume your distro has a working version with a default home page configured. There are plenty of tutorials around, and Nginx is really quite easy when you try to understand it, but it does take a little time and effort.

Comment: @Tim, it turned out that the problem was with an extra security setting on the hosting service (Amazon), that I didn't even know existed until now. Nginx had nothing to do with it. So, I guess we all learned something today... just because someone is having a problem with something, doesn't mean they haven't put the effort in to learning about it, it might be something completely different having an influence.

Comment: I think the lesson here is to share more environment details. I'm certified and experienced with AWS and can often help. What setting was it - NACL, security group, subnetting, routing, or something else?

Comment: @Tim, sure, more environment details can be helpful, but, you know, it's not always so clear where to draw the line. I've been setting up servers on other places like Digital Ocean where this kind of thing doesn't ever come up, and therefore didn't know that it even could be a factor. In any case, it was something called "EC2", and/or "security groups".

Comment: Security groups is the AWS firewall - one of two anyway. EC2 is their virtual machines. This is why I asked for the curl, if that worked then the answer would've been obvious - security groups or NACLs. AWS isn't always the simplest environment, but it's great when you understand it.

Comment: @Questioner you may want to post your findings and how you specifically solved the issue (as you previously explained) in an answer below. Could be useful for other people who might face the same issue.